# Flutter Desktop run Powershell commands

Tags: flutter

I want to ask if it is possible to run PowerShell Code with Flutter Desktop for Windows.
I found the package process_run on pub.dev.
With that i can run Shell Commands but i have to do a workaround and start a PowerShell command with that.
is there a direct way to send PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/tekartik/process_run.dart/issues/35) on that same repo asking about Powershell

Based on the answer from the repo owner, you may do something like:

```dart
// You can run a command
await shell.run('powershell -c "pwd"');
// You can run a power shell script
await shell.run('powershell script.ps1');
```